# Подскажите как привязать код python к telegram bot (aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Здорова всем. Пишу **telegram_bot** который бы скачивал **mp3** с **YouTube** и отправлял пользователю аудио в дальнейшем хочу написать будильник, чтобы пользователь сам решал под какую музыку вставать.

Код для скачивания с **YouTube** , он работает замечательно проблема в том, что не могу понять как правильно его 'подвязать' к **aiogram_bot**, при добавлении этого куска кода к **aiogram_bot** скачивания не происходит.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

audio = str(input('link url '))
ydl_opts = {'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio','preferredcodec': 'mp3','preferredquality': '192'}]}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([audio])
```

Сам телеграм бот.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import keybords as kb
import logging 


from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from config import *
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Command

import os
import nest_asyncio


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token = API_TOKEN_Music_bot )
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())


nest_asyncio.apply()

# аналог input() in the python
class Form(StatesGroup):
    music_link = State()
    

@dp.message_handler(commands=['music'])
async def alarm(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Plsm,input link for downloads mmusic")
    await Form.music_link.set()
    

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.music_link)
async def answerDay(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    answer_mmusic_link = message.text
    await state.update_data(answer_mmusic_link1 = answer_mmusic_link )
    answer_mmusic_link1 =  data.get("answer_music_link1")


    ydl_opts = {'postprocessors': [{'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio','preferredcodec': 'mp3','preferredquality': '192'}]}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        audio = ydl.download([answer_mmusic_link1])
    await bot.download_file('/home/dus/Desktop/musica', "answer_mmusic_link1")
    await state.finish()
if __name__ =='__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp,skip_updates=(True))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не используйте библиотеку youtube_dl, она является синхронный и будет тормозить работы всего бота. Или переписывайте на асинк его или же найдите другую библиотеку асинхронную.